# how to solve $\sqrt{x^2 -2x} -x =0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I factor and solve the equation: $\sqrt{x^2 -2x} - x = 0$ ? I can see how $0$ and $-1$ are the answers, but I'm not sure how to show it mathematically, other than with substituting in these values! :D ty all!

Comment: Move $x$ to the right-side and square.

Comment: What is root(x^2 - 2x)? Did you mean $\sqrt{x^2 - 2x}$? How is $-1$ an answer then?

Comment: aah ok thanks :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given with : $\sqrt{(x^2 - 2x)} - x = 0$

Try to analyze the equation. Here, in LHS, the term $-x$ is simple and can be transposed to the RHS. While, the term with the square root may irritate you later. In order to get away from this, you will need to square it. Remember that : $(\sqrt{x})^2  =x$

Therefore, let us first transpose $-x$ to the RHS. When it will be transposed, its sign will reverse and thus, will change to $+$ .

You get : 
$\sqrt{(x^2 - 2x)} = \color{blue}{x} $

You see what have I done here? I just transposed -x to RHS.

Now, as I said earlier, to get rid of the square roots, you need to square both sides.

$$\left(\sqrt{x^2-2x}\right)^2 = x^2 \\
x^2 - 2x = x^2 \\
$$ 
Notice that the terms $x^2$ are in both sides, so, they will cancel out.

You get : $$ -2x = 0 \\
x =? $$

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x=0\iff \sqrt{x^2-2x}=x$$
and by squaring we get
$$x^2-2x=x^2\iff x=0$$

Notice finally that we accept this answer since $x=0$ is  non negative.

Comment: Short and sweet!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x=0\rightarrow\sqrt{x^2-2x}=x\rightarrow x^2-2x=x^2\rightarrow -2x=0\rightarrow x=0.$$

We get $x=0$ as the only solution.